# How to enable resource shrinking in Android Studio with experimental Gradle for NDK?

Tags: android-ndk, gradle-experimental

How do you enable [resource shrinking](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#shrink-resources) in Android Studio when using the experimental Gradle for the NDK?

Adding `shrinkResources = true` to the Gradle settings file next to `minifyEnabled = true` fails with an obscure error.

Comment: Related issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204089